# SQL ERROR 1291 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:... - but all types match?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm creating a stored procedure called 'updateParameter'. When executed it throws SQL ERROR 1292, which I chased through the internet to probably mean, that I am comparing two mismatching types in a where clause, which are converted to double. There are no double values in any tables or functions.

Background: MYSQL, version 8.

Here is the table, from which the procedure tries to read some values:

```
CREATE TABLE `param` (
  `model` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `parameter` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `aggregator` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SUM',
  `statement` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `constant` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`model`,`parameter`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

Here are the relevant parts of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updateParameter`(
    `model` VARCHAR(45),
    `parameter` VARCHAR(45),
    `symbol` VARCHAR(10),
    `frq` VARCHAR(2),
    `reportingDate` DATE
)
thisProc: BEGIN
    DECLARE `statement` VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE `acc` VARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE argname VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE argparam VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE argstatement VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE argaccount VARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE argperiods INT;
    DECLARE argshift INT;
    DECLARE result FLOAT;
    DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT 
                paramargs.parameter, 
                paramargs.argname,
                paramargs.argstatement, 
                paramargs.argaccount,
                paramargs.argperiods,
                paramargs.argshift
            FROM paramargs
            WHERE
                paramargs.model = model and
                paramargs.parameter = parameter and
                paramargs.frq = frq and
                (param_check(paramargs.model, paramargs.argstatement, paramargs.argaccount) 
                OR 
                aggregator_check(paramargs.argstatement, paramargs.argaccount)) AND
                NOT cpy_param_isUpdated(model, paramargs.argstatement, paramargs.argaccount, symbol, frq); 
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    
    SELECT `param`.`statement`
        INTO `statement`
        FROM `param` WHERE
            `param`.`model` = `model` AND
            `param`.`parameter` = `parameter`
        LIMIT 1;
    call log_message('OK', 'updateParameter:' + parameter + ':statement', statement);
...
```

Here is how the procedure is called:

```
call updateParameter(
    'VAL2.0',
    'Growth FurtherExpenses',
    'IBM',
    'q',
    STR_TO_DATE('2023-12-31','%Y-%m-%d')
);
```

Executing that command produces the ERROR 1292. I extended the code snippet to include all lines before the critical select statement (the cursor seems to work fine).

If I enter the following:

```
SELECT param.statement 
FROM param WHERE
    param.model = 'VAL2.0' AND
    param.parameter = 'Growth FurtherExpenses'
limit 1;
```

...then I do get a proper result: 'KPI'

I used some logging messages and stop execution on error to trace the error to this select statement - but I really do not see, how a type mismatch could exist. I verfied, the arguments are as in the direct select statement below. It should produce the same result and write it into 'statement'.

Am I overlooking something obvious?

Best,

YeOldHinnerk

Comment: You should include the full error message and the procedure being used. That said, using potentially reserved, unescaped names like `parameter` and `constant` may lead to unexpected bugs. Try escaping them with backticks: `\`parameter\``

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9SAXqi493SXt54cGHKJ7aw/0

Comment: never ever use variable names that are the same as column names use instead p_model for example

Comment: Excessive Backtick-quoting did not solve the issue.

Comment: Variable names that are same as column names do not seem an issue. Maybe it is not best practice, but it doesn't seem to be the root of the problem.

Comment: Will extend code snippets so that it can be reproduced in fiddle hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and it was not in the code snippets:
On the next line, I was tryping to print the parameter as part of a string - and I used '+' instead of concat...

Thank you for everyone looking at it.

Comment: A good reason to always include the full code - sometimes it's silly mistakes we all make that lead to horrendous error messages.